# Convert LocalDateTime to human readable format in JQuery

Tags: jquery, datetime-format

This might be something very trivial but I am unable to figure it out.I need to convert date coming in 2016-10-07T04:30 format to more readable form like "7th Oct,16 4:30". Is there a plugin to do this or any JQuery function.

Any help ?

Comment: you can use moment.js

Comment: Also you can do it using multiple line code of javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this:

```
//Bind your control on your $(document).ready function and add this:

 function mtdBindControls() {
//Just change your ID after '#'
        $('#strSelectedDateFrom').datetimepicker({
            format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
d= new Date('2016-10-07T04:30'); // create new date variable
readable =  d.toString(); //create a more readable string
console.log(readable)
```

or

```
 console.log((new Date('2016-10-07T04:30')).toString()); // do it in a single line
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of JavaScript date functions:

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.toLocaleDateString();
```

This will give you the date in the format currently set in the browser. There are a large number of date functions which will give you all you need. As mentioned in another answer `ToString()` is the most straightforward of these.

There are many references to these functions on the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

for changing the date format to human readable date string javascript doc provide a function called to toDateString();

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var date = new Date.toDateString();
   console.log(date);
});
```